# Unit of Work Questions - Nhibernate (Isolation Level & What else would be in a UoW)

Tags: nhibernate, unit-of-work

I am looking into the UoW pattern and have 3 questions.

```
  public class UnitofWork : unitofwork.Models.IUnitofWork
    {
        private readonly ITransaction transaction;
        private readonly ISession session;

        public UnitofWork(ISession session)
        {
            this.session = session;
            session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Auto;
            transaction = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            if (!transaction.IsActive)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Oops! We don't have an active transaction");
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }

        public void Rollback()
        {
            if (transaction.IsActive)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (session.IsOpen)
            {
                session.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

1. I just learning about "IsolationLevels" and I am wondering which one should you be using? What happens if you need to make use of multiple "IsolationLevels" for different transactions? How would you configure your UoW(would you make multiple implementations of the above class?)
2. Other then Rollback and Commit was usually goes into the UoW? I know stuff like creating,updating,getting queries would go into a repository(if your using this pattern) So what else would you typicall see in it?
3. I copied this UoW from some site(don't have it on hand right now) and made changes it to fit my needs(for instance I am using ninject so I felt there was no point in the UoW taking in the sessionFactory and opening a session in the UoW)

I am wondering what is the Dispose for? I seen this a few times before(some seem to implement IDispose).

I don't actually use it right now in any of my code. I am wondering if it is necessary for me as I mentioned I am using ninject and that handles the session(ie closes it once I am done)

```
  public void Dispose()
        {
            if (session.IsOpen)
            {
                session.Close();
            }
        }
```

**Edit**

I added this to my unit of work

```
   public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        transaction = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    }

    public void BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel level)
    {
        transaction = session.BeginTransaction(level);
    }
```

I removed it from the constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISession itself is a unit-of-work implementation, so implementing your own is entirely optional.

1. [IsolationLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel.aspx) is declared in the System.Data namespace. ReadCommitted is the most commonly used; this is also the default for SQL Server. I tried using Chaos once just because I like the name but SQL Server doesn't support it.
2. The code you have in the question creates a transaction as soon as the session is opened, so it's a transaction per UOW implementation; note that if you call Commit or Rollback, any additional operations will occur outside of transaction scope. I really dislike this and prefer to control my own transaction scope, so I would have a BeginTransaction in my UOW.
3. Classes that implement IDisposable must implement the Dispose method and should be used in a `using` block or disposed of manually. It means that the class has clean up operations that need to run, such as closing the ISession. Here, the Dispose method should just call ISession.Dispose instead of just closing the session.

Comment: I still don't get point one. I know I don't have to specify one but still don't get it them. With point 2 I just realized that now. I was playing around with a scenario where I would have to commit some stuff then do another commit again. So now I have unitOfWork.BeginTransaction() --- See Edit. That needs to be called. I am beginning to think this is the way to go otherwise your got 1 commit or 1 rollback and your out. With point 3 that makes a bit more sense but like I said I think ninject and ninject mvc 3 plugin take care of that stuff.

Comment: Wikipedia (http://bit.ly/oZrVT4) has a good article about transaction isolation. ReadCommitted is the best choice for most applications. Ninject will take care of disposing any objects that implement IDisposable. But since you're wrapping the ISession in your UOW you should dispose of it there or construct it using Ninject.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean "since you're wrapping the ISession in your UoW". How I understand how I have ninject setup it will dispose of it at the end of each http request. So why does it matter where it is?

Comment: Ninject should take care of it. However, I would have the UOW implement IDisposable and dispose of the ISession there. An ISession represents a database connection and I wouldn't take any chances with it.